# Primefaces p:tree worked successfully in v4 and failed to work in v5, v5.1, 5.2, 5.3 and 6

Tags: primefaces

I developed and web application using Mojarra jsf 2.2 and Primefaces 4, Wildfly as web server and Eclipse Neon as IDE. and it was working nice. when I was trying to migrate to Primefaces 5 everything worked fine except p:tree failed to fire any select events. same thing occurred with v5.1, 5.2, 5.3 and 6.
So please any help will be appreciated

below is p:tree code snippet:

```
<h:form id="barForm">
                    <p:tree id="treeSingle" value="#{treeBackBean.root}" var="node"
                        selectionMode="single" selection="#{treeBackBean.selectedNode}"
                        dir="rtl" style="height: 100%; width: 200px;">
                        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{treeBackBean.onNodeSelect}" />
                        <p:treeNode>
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{node}" />
                        </p:treeNode>
                    </p:tree>
                </h:form>
```

backing been classes are:

```
public class TreeNodeData {
public static final int NODE_TYPE_ROOT = 0;
public static final int NODE_TYPE_BRANCH = 1;
public static final int NODE_TYPE_LEAF = 2;

private String descreption;
private String url;
private int nodeType;

public TreeNodeData(String descreption,String url,int nodeType ){
    this.descreption = descreption;
    this.url = url;
    this.nodeType = nodeType;
}

public String getDescreption() {
    return descreption;
}

public void setDescreption(String descreption) {
    this.descreption = descreption;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return descreption;
}

public int getNodeType() {
    return nodeType;
}

public void setNodeType(int nodeType) {
    this.nodeType = nodeType;
}
```

}

I also used AppUtil to get property value from properties file.

```
import services.AppUtil;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.NodeSelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TreeBackBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private TreeNode root;
private TreeNode selectedNode;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@PostConstruct
public void builtTree() {
    TreeNodeData nodeData = new TreeNodeData("Root", "", TreeNodeData.NODE_TYPE_ROOT);
    root = new DefaultTreeNode(nodeData, null);

    nodeData = new TreeNodeData(AppUtil.getPropertyValue("labels", "menuControlPanel"), "",
            TreeNodeData.NODE_TYPE_BRANCH);
    TreeNode settingsMenu = new DefaultTreeNode(nodeData, root);

 try{nodeData = new TreeNodeData(AppUtil.getPropertyValue("labels",          "applicationAdministartionSubMenu"), "",
                    TreeNodeData.NODE_TYPE_BRANCH);
            TreeNode applicationAdministartionSubMenu = new                 DefaultTreeNode(nodeData, settingsMenu);

 nodeData = new TreeNodeData(AppUtil.getPropertyValue("labels", "usersRoles"),
                                        "userRole.xhtml",                 TreeNodeData.NODE_TYPE_LEAF);
            TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode(nodeData,   applicationAdministartionSubMenu);
            //
            nodeData = new   TreeNodeData(AppUtil.getPropertyValue("labels", "Catogeries"),
                    "Catogery.xhtml", TreeNodeData.NODE_TYPE_LEAF);
            TreeNode node2 = new DefaultTreeNode(nodeData, applicationAdministartionSubMenu);
            //
            nodeData = new TreeNodeData(AppUtil.getPropertyValue("labels", "Units"),
                    "Unit.xhtml", TreeNodeData.NODE_TYPE_LEAF);
            TreeNode node3 = new DefaultTreeNode(nodeData, applicationAdministartionSubMenu);
            //
applicationAdministartionSubMenu.setExpanded(true);
 ///...........etc
   } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    }

public TreeNode getRoot() {
    return root;
}

public TreeNode getSelectedNode() {
    return selectedNode;
}

public void setSelectedNode(TreeNode selectedNode) {
    this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
}

public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {
TreeNodeData treeNodeData = (TreeNodeData) event.getTreeNode().getData();
//remaining selection code goes here
//it just redirecting to selected page.
}

public void expand(TreeNode treeNode) {
    if (treeNode != null)
        if (treeNode.getParent() != null) {
            treeNode.getParent().setExpanded(true);
            expand(treeNode.getParent());
        }
}

}//class end
```

Comment: Please improve your title. And the PrimeFaces showcase works. Find the differences

Comment: @Kukeltje I learned from PrimeFaces showcase and I know it is work fine there. but i does not work at least for me with any latest versions after v4,,,,I do not know why.
Anyway Thanks,, I appreciate that.

Comment: I used ajaxStatus in xhtml body <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();" /> <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Processing..." draggable="true" closable="false"> <p:graphicImage library="images" name="ajaxloadingbar.gif" /> </p:dialog> it seems that it somehow block ajax select events for p:tree when I set p:tree ajax select event global attribute to false it works fine with all versions. but this way make a lot o other problems since it disable firing other actions......eg: commondButton and commondLink stop working.

Comment: You can edit your question. Makes the code more readable